# In WPF, is it possible to represent the same ViewModel with different Views, based on some condition?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, user-experience

I am making a TreeView with multiple levels of information being displayed. What I am hoping to achieve, is to show a different view when the sub-tree is expanded and closed. So, when just looking at the list, I want to make a view which shows a brief status overview of my more detailed view that would be visible if you expanded that item in the list.

I know I could just create 2 viewmodels implementing the same Interface, and based on a boolean IsExpanded, I could set the ActiveViewModel to one or the other, but I was just curious if I could just have the one viewmodel and change its view based on that boolean instead to save memory.

-OR-

Alternatively, should I just put 2 StackPanels into the same View, and then bind a visibility to be inverse of each other, so only one can be shown at a time?

-CODE-

Here is my current code (Private information removed / generic representation):

Xaml:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<Style x:Key="TreeViewItemStyle" TargetType="TreeViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource Univers57}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded}" />
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<TreeView x:Name="TreeView"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ItemViewModels}"
              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle}">

        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate
                DataType="{x:Type viewModel:ItemViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding IsVisible}>
                    <Image Source="../../Images/Image.png" Height="24" Width="24"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item.Name}" />
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">Dispatch</Button>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding IsOtherVisible}>
                    <Image Source="../../Images/Image2.png" Height="24" Width="24"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item.Name}" />
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">Dispatch</Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate
                DataType="{x:Type viewModel:TaskViewModel}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Task.Name}" Width="200"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>

        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```

Both the ItemViewModel and TaskViewModel inherit from 'TreeViewModel' which implements INotifyPropertyChanged, and has IsExpanded and IsSelected.

IsVisible on the StackPanel Binding should be set based on IsExpanded's value. (It only shows up once you expand the item. So, one stackpanel or the other should show up).

I have just had a play with the WPF Visual Tree tools in VS2015 and it looks like the IsExpanded isnt being changed when I expand/collapse the tree items. It only sets a value during creation of the viewmodels, after that it will never change - even though they physically open and close when running the program.

Comment: You can bind to the `TreeViewItem.IsExpanded` property to set a flag that in turn controls visibility of the parent item's visuals. Unfortunately, without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you've tried, along with a precise explanation of what that code does and how that's different from what you want, the question is far too broad to be answered concisely on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I will put my code up now.

Comment: Typically this is done via a custom DataTemplateSelector.

Answer (score 0):

Have  managed to find a solution.

Firstly, needed to set 2 Way Binding on the binding to IsExpanded.

Secondly, I have overridden / hidden IsExpanded by declaring it as new in the derived class.

Now when set() gets called on IsExpanded, I can make a change to the IsVisible and IsOtherVisible before sending OnPropertyChange(); Now that I can change the IsVisible's, they can fire their own OnPropertyChange() and all is good in the world again.